# Regular expression modification to make captured group nullable or optional

Tags: regex

We have existing regex for

```
ROOT =/(.*)/(-?\d+)/(.*)/(-?\d+)$

ROOT=/ANY_ENTITY/ENTITY1/ENTITY2/ENTITY3$
```

where regexes for each are:

```
ANY_ENTITY= (.*) , 
ENTITY1 = (-?\d+) ,
ENTITY2 = (.*) ,
ENTITY3 = (-?\d+)
```

So for input :`{ROOT =/AID/2/3/1}`,below are captured groups:

```
#1  AID
#2  2
#3  3
#4  1
```

Now we need to modify this regex to make ENTITY1  optional. 
 i.e For input without ENTITY1=2,: `ROOT =/AID/3/1` in previous example;the captured groups should be:

```
#1  AID
#2  null
#3  3
#4  1
```

I tried making ENTITY1 optional with this modified regex(note / associated with ENTITY1 is also optional)

```
ROOT =/(.*)(?:/(-?\d+))?/(.*)/(-?\d+)$
```

though it passes as expected for input:
    `ROOT =/AID/3/1` but fails
 for valid ENTITY1 value: `ROOT =/AID/2/3/1` with below incorrect captured groups:

```
#1  AID/2
#2  null
#3  3
#4  1
```

Comment: Which programing language are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be certain changes to the regex in order to capture those optionals properly

We can have a regex like

```
ROOT =/([^/]*)/(?:(-?\d+)/)?(.*)/(-?\d+)$
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/mJ8jG0/1)

**Changes made**

- `([^/]*)` The first capturing group. Here we changed `.*` to the negated character class so that it matches anything other than `/`. This is imported because `.*` is greedy and may at times match our `ENTITY1` as well which we dont want to.
- `(?:(-?\d+)/)?` Second capturing group. See the position of quantifier `?`. We need to make entire `ENTITY1/`  optional, and to just `ENTITY` so the quantifier must come after the `/`

Comment: genius...thanks ...on primary inputs  it works okay ,i need to try it with more complicated inputs

Comment: @MominFakhruddin Do let me know if you come up with some fails in some inputs :)